# indicate any char in a string to do a comparison in shell

Tags: regex, string, numbers, compare, conditional-statements

i have another little problem that i can't find in this forum.

i have a directory called Contacts which contains files. each file have the same format name: name_secondname.ct

but in my directory i can have more than one file with the same name.
an example:

```
mario_winans.ct
mario_winans1.ct
mario_winans2.ct
```

i have a shell script:

```
j=0
FILES=/home/accounts/studenti/id913usr/Scrivania/Contacts/*
nome_file="mario_winans"    
for f in $FILES ; do
    filename=${f##*/}
    if [[ "$nome_file(anything or any number).ct" == "$filename" ]] ; then
    (( j++ ))
    fi

done    
nome_file="mario_winans$j"
echo $nome_file
```

that take a path of a directory, save a name into a variable called nome_file, loop through files of the directory, take a file name at each iteration (put it in a var called filename) and compare nome_file with filename. since the dir can contain file with the same name numbered at the end (like that: mario_winans2.ct) i want to compare ONLY the name and if the two names are equal i want to increase a counter (j in my case) and create a new variable with the name numbered at the end with j.

in my example, remember, in the directory i have

```
mario_winans.ct
mario_winans1.ct
mario_winans2.ct
```

the variable nome_file contain "mario_winans"

the script compare nome_file with mario_winans.ct and j increase to 1, then compare nome_file with mario_winans1.ct and j increase to 2, then compare nome_file with mario_winans2.ct and j increase to 3

out of the loop i modify my variable nome_file ("mario_winans") adding j at the end (nome_file="mario_winans$j")

this is how it work.
i have a problem in my if condition. the part (anything or any number) is the problem. i want to compare ONLY the two name and not the number at the end but i dont know how i can say "anything or any number" into the string

i hope to have been clear.

Comment: what flavor or regex are you using ? javascript ? c# ?

Answer (score 0):

you just want to count the files?

```
DIR=/home/accounts/studenti/id913usr/Scrivania/Contacts/
nome_file="mario_winans"
shopt -s nullglob
files=( $DIR$nome_file*.ct )
shopt -u nullglob
j=${#files[*]}
```

Comment: i add to your script this code: echo $j, to print j
i execute your script and it give to me this output: {0files[*]}